# difference size of list make Dataframe in pandas and how to make dummies

Tags: python, pandas

```
  index            0          1         2         3         4        5  \
0         0       Action  Adventure   Fantasy    Sci-Fi       NaN      NaN   
1         1       Action  Adventure   Fantasy       NaN       NaN      NaN   
2         2       Action  Adventure  Thriller       NaN       NaN      NaN   
3         3       Action   Thriller       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN   
4         4  Documentary        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN   
5         5       Action  Adventure    Sci-Fi       NaN       NaN      NaN   
6         6       Action  Adventure   Romance       NaN       NaN      NaN   
7         7    Adventure  Animation    Comedy    Family   Fantasy  Musical   
8         8       Action  Adventure    Sci-Fi       NaN       NaN      NaN   
9         9    Adventure     Family   Fantasy   Mystery       NaN      NaN
```

i have data like this...

but i have no idea to make dummies with difference size of data frame data in pandas python....

```
Action  Adventure   Fantasy Sci-Fi  Thriller    Ducumentary Romance Animation   Comedy  family  Fantasy Musical Mystery
0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
8   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
```

like this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but first need remove first column by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), then create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

Output have duplicated index, so need `groupby` by `index` and aggregate `max`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.drop('index', axis=1).stack()).groupby(level=0).max()
#alternative solution
#df = pd.get_dummies(df.iloc[:, 1:].stack()).groupby(level=0).max()
print (df)
   Action  Adventure  Animation  Comedy  Documentary  Family  Fantasy  \
0       1          1          0       0            0       0        1   
1       1          1          0       0            0       0        1   
2       1          1          0       0            0       0        0   
3       1          0          0       0            0       0        0   
4       0          0          0       0            1       0        0   
5       1          1          0       0            0       0        0   
6       1          1          0       0            0       0        0   
7       0          1          1       1            0       1        1   
8       1          1          0       0            0       0        0   
9       0          1          0       0            0       1        1   

   Musical  Mystery  Romance  Sci-Fi  Thriller  
0        0        0        0       1         0  
1        0        0        0       0         0  
2        0        0        0       0         1  
3        0        0        0       0         1  
4        0        0        0       0         0  
5        0        0        0       1         0  
6        0        0        1       0         0  
7        1        0        0       0         0  
8        0        0        0       1         0  
9        0        1        0       0         0
```

Comment: Um... i gave u wrong information about what i want...
1_Family, 3_Family be a same column... so sorry....

Answer (score 1):

House keeping:
make sure that pesky `index` column is out of the way

```
df = df.drop('index', 1)
```

using `pd.values_counts`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Or equivalently

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts, 1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: if i have two votes i gave you too.. 
thank u very much ~ have a good day

Comment: @ByungjunLee You can up-vote as well as accept an answer.